# Why is "npm install" looking for a file that doesn't exist (package.json) on a fresh NodeJS installation?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

`Hello, World!`

I am having trouble getting NPM working.

First, I installed node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ (the 64-bit .msi, on Windows 10, Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362).  Node `-v` is 12.16.3.

Using Powershell, I navigated to the nodejs directory created in the install.  Then I attempted `npm install`, which ultimately drew a series of errors beginning with "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\nodejs\package.json' ".

The nodejs directory contains a file called "package-lock.json", but no "package.json".

Renaming the "-lock" file did not fix the error.

I've read on this site that Node came with NPM pre-installed.  I can run `npm -v` without a problem ("6.14.4" returned) but trying `npm start` gives me the same error as `npm install` (cannot find package.json).

I have uninstalled Node & reinstalled twice, same problem.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a package.json file for every project using npm libraries, whether or not you are going to publish your code anywhere.

The easiest way is to run `npm init` and answer the questions, then npm will create the package.json file.

(Or take a look at [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) for other ways to run init, like `npm init -y` to just generate a plain package.json that you can manually edit.)

BTW, package-lock.json is [a different kind of file](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/package-lock-json.html) that's generated to say which versions of each transitive dependency were installed. It doesn't have the same format as package.json; don't mix them.